# SOQL query, formulate query for more than one

Tags: php, salesforce, soql

I'm making a search box in php accessing data from a SOQL salesforce database. So far I have this:

`$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone From Contact WHERE FirstName = '$var'";`

Which works perfectly fine. However, how would I make it so that let's say `$var` could be the phone number. So if it doesn't match the First name, search for a match in Phone number, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone From Contact WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$var%' OR Phone LIKE '%$var%'";
```

using LIKE instead of = you can match parts of names, for example searching dav would result in David and Daves both being returned.  The % are wildcard place holders.

Comment: I also agree with Dreaded's post below, you want to clean the $var to prevent SQL injection.  If this is on a closed intranet, then you may not have to worry about it, but it is good practice.

Comment: nice! Thanks. I have one problem with %$var% though, even when it's empty I'm getting all the results. Is there a way to tell it that var must be at least not empty?
EDIT: Actually I encountered another problem. When I use or I'm not getting any results :S

Comment: you probably want a javascript validation for this, so that if the user does not input anything they are alerted before actually sending the data off to the server. Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: Oh nevermind I fixed it. Turns out the mysql escape string didn't work .

Comment: you need to connect to db before calling mysql escape string. this is important to prevent someone hacking into your db easily

Comment: Yes I understand why it's important, but for whatever reasons whenever I use the function on $var, the query doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using a SOQL database instead of a MYSQL, but that's the case :(

Comment: if you cant get that to work, use addslashes;  $var = addslashes($var);  this will take care of most of the problems, its not 100% secure, but far better than not doing it.

Comment: This will also prevent any problems when searching for names that have apostrophes in them.  I understand there aren't many first names this would apply to, but when you eventually expand to last names Im sure you will run into this problem.

Comment: Thank you! Let's hope everything goes well.

Answer (score 1):

This should check if there is match in firstname or no match in first name but finds a match in phone

```
 $var=mysql_real_escape_string($var); //protect your sql entries from sql injection, make sure to validate
 $query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone From Contact WHERE FirstName = '$var' OR (FirstName !='$var' AND Phone='$var') ";
```

Or if you don't mind if there is match here or there you can use `or`.  which is better performance-wise than the previous query

```
 $query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone From Contact WHERE FirstName = '$var' OR Phone='$var' ";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For whatever odd reasons or is not working for me. If I just have a single search element then it works, but if I use two it doesn't work. I also made sure the field I'm searching for exists.

Comment: can you post an example of $var that doesn't work even though it does exist in db?  `=` will match exactly, `Like '%%'` will match using wildcat. so in the above answer the string needs to match exactly. if it is `abcd` in db, then only `abcd` matches, not `abcd ` with a space neither `abc`.  also make sure to validate `$var`. if it is empty, then don't search for it.  For example $var=trim($var); then `if (!empty($var))`

Comment: Oh I found the reason why. using mysql real escape string didn't work for the query for some reasons! Is it because I'm using SOQL?